# Sql query for updating database if value is not null?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-update

I am having a table which has about 17 fields. I need to perform frequent updates in this table. But the issue is **each time I may be updating only a few fields**. Whats the best way to write a query for updating in such a scenario? I am looking for an option in which the *value gets updated only if it is not null*.

For example I have four fields in database Say A,B,C,D.
User updates the value of say D. All other values remains the same. So I want an update query which updates only the value of D keeping the others unaltered.
 SO if i put a,b and c as null and d with the value supplied by user I want to write an update query which only updates the value of d as a,b and c is null.
Is it something achievable?

I am using SQLite database.

Could someone please throw some light into it?

Comment: Which database? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Comment: What database do you Use? MySQL? Oracle ?  SQL Server ? You can do such a thing using triggers (Before update). If your database supports it.

Comment: "if it is not null", what is IT?

Comment: I am using sqlite ..... I am looking for an sql command for updating...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Without knowing your database it's tough to be specific.  In SQL Server the syntax would be something like ...

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET 
        Field1 = IsNull(@Field1, Field1),
        Field2 = IsNull(@Field2, Field2),
        Field3 = IsNull(@Field3, Field3)
WHERE 
     <your criteria here>
```

**EDIT**

Since you specified SQLLite ...replace my `IsNull` function with `COALESCE()`  or alternately look at the `IfNull` function.

Comment: Just keep in mind that this means that you can never set a column back to NULL using this stored procedure once it's been set.

Comment: In MySQL the @ is not needed, i.e. `Field1 = IsNull(Field1Value)` seems to work fine

Comment: @Janac Meena: The name of the function to use in Mysql for this cases is `IfNull`

Answer (score 2):

Posting a SQL Server solution with 2 tables for posterity. Query joins two tables and updates the values that are present. Otherwise original value is maintained.

tables = table1, table2 each having field1 and field2

```
update t1 WITH (ROWLOCK)
set T1.Field2 = ISNULL(T2.Field2,T1.Field2)
from Table1 T1 Join Table2 T2 
    ON T1.Field1 = T2.Field1
```